# Paint Component Method not working for JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paint, paintcomponent

I'm trying to paint an image on the screen after trying to use JLabel's and am now trying the paintComponent method. I tried inserting breakpoints after seeing no results and the method doesn't get called, and nothing appears. What should I do? Here is my important code-

`

```
     public void createWindow(){        

            frame.setVisible(true);  
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(xSize, ySize);
            frame.setLocation(0, 0);
            frame.addComponentListener(this);
            //frame.add(im);             

    }
```

`public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(placeholder, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
        g.drawString("Hello", 100, 100);
    }`

Also I'm using a JFrame instead of JPanel or component if that makes a difference.

Comment: `Here is my important code-` not dis_agreee, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about a.m. issue

Comment: What are you overriding? AFAIK `paintComponent` is not from `JFrame`

Comment: In my code I have the @Override I forgot to type it in here though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JFrame` does not have a `paintComponent` method. You should avoid painting directly to a frame and instead use a `JPanel` and override its `paintComponent` method

You should also make use of the @Override annotation, which will raise a compiler exception if the parent class does not have the method you are trying to override...

Comment: How should I implement the JPanel?

Comment: Create a custom class that extends from JPanel, once you implemented the paint method, you'll need to add it to the frame...

Comment: I just realised, you're not calling super.paintComponent, this is very important and you should defiantly do this ;)

Comment: thanks i have it working now and yes i added the super.paintComponent